# Why should I use a UIToolbar vs using a UIView?

Tags: ios, user-interface, uiview, uitoolbar

I'm building an instant messenger app in iOS. In particular I'm implementing the UI for a conversation in the most typical way, that is placing an input bar at the bottom of the view (`UICollectionView` to be clear) that scrolls above the keyboard.
Now, I'm wondering if I should implement this view as a `UIToolbar` with `UIBarButtonItem`s instead of a custom `UIView` with `UIButton`s. What are the advantages of a `UIToolbar`?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I don't think there is much difference other than convenience.  With a UIToolbar you get the following:

- UIBarButton items are arguably simpler to add to a tool bar and the
  layout is automatic, whereas it is a bit more complicated adding
  buttons to a view.
- You can set `hidesBottomBarWhenPushed` on the view controllers to
  hide the bar when a view controller is pushed to the nav stack.
- Looks more familiar to other apps, including Apple's own apps.

If you use a UIView with buttons you have more flexibility in the appearance but you have to do a bit more work, but other than that I can't really see much difference.

Answer (score 3):

UIToolbar will provide automatic placing of your buttons, saving you from pain of placing those buttons. It was designed specifically for this reason.